# How to set a text inside a button to drop the shadow in JavaFX

Tags: button, text, fonts, javafx, shadow

So i have a custom button class in controller and i want to make the font which will be Inside of button to drop a shadow. i've tried to use -fx-stroke, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Buttons which i want to use will be generated during the program. i'm not familiar with CSS so i just used some examples. Now i have this

```
mineButton(int x, int y,boolean difficult){ 
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        Font s = new Font(13);
        if (difficult){
            this.setMaxSize(35, 35);
            this.setMinSize(20, 20);
            this.setPrefSize(20, 20);
            this.setFont(new Font(8));
        } else {
            this.setMaxSize(35,35);
            this.setMinSize(33,33);
            this.setPrefSize(34,34);
        }
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border,       
        -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;\n" +
                "    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;" +
                "    -fx-background-radius: 5, 4, 3;" + 
                " -fx-text-fill: white; -fx-font-weight: bold;" ); 
    }
```

Comment: Adding a stroke to font will be also good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [setGraphic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-) method to change the appearance of the Node inside your Button.

Here's a documentation with an example about how to do it: [Using JavaFX UI Controls - Button](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm).

You can then apply CSS to that custom Node of yours.

Example:

```
Button button = new Button();
Label label = new Label("Click Me!");
label.setStyle("-fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , black , 8 , 0.0 , 2 , 0 )");
button.setGraphic(label);
```